# Get fullname by username using SSSD

Tags: linux, ldap, sssd

The OS uses SSSD to authenticate users via LDAP. It has no X server running. I can run `id <username>` to get the uid of the user. And the users can login to the system and their full name is displayed.

Is there a way to get the full name or display name of a specified user via a shell command?

Answer (score 3):

`getent passwd <username>` should do the trick.

Comment: There is no full name.

Comment: Well, what can I say. It works for me in two setups: one with sssd against FreeIPA, the other with sssd against Active Directory.

Comment: If this doesn't work, you may need to adjust your `ldap_user_gecos` setting in sssd.conf as your AD environment may have empty `gecos` or `cn` attributes for users. You can try adding the missing attributes in AD or using `ldap_user_gecos = displayName` in order to use the Display Name attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
finger -l <username>
```

(or other methods like `getent passwd <username>`).

Comment: Doesn't work. Name is empty. I think because the user never logged in(?)

Answer (score 0):

*sssd* 1.13+ provides a D-BUS query interface.

See also: [sssd -- D-Bus Interface: Users and Groups](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/design_pages/dbus_users_and_groups.html)

Comment: Maybe this would work. But my system has no X server running.

Comment: This does not need X server running. The *dbus-daemon* is also running on head-less servers.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your UNIX version you can use

```
echo $LOGNAME
```

or

```
echo $USER
```

If both *$LOGNAME* and *$USER* are present they should match.

Comment: I asked for the fullname. I already have the username. But I want this for a given username, not for the current one. I need to make it more clear.